# Wordpress: sum custom meta_values from all posts by a user

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok, so right now I have a working code, that basically echo the total amount of posts for `meta_key` _heart_this for a specific user:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => '_heart_this', 'author' =>  1,  ) );

   echo $query->found_posts; ?>
```

However, some posts have `meta_value` of 2, 3 etc..

So I want to sum the total amount of `meta_value` and echo, because right now the number I get is inaccurate obviously.

I'm almost there, need a bit of guidance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same advice [as yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68299338/1427878) – loop over the result records then, and sum up the values …

Comment: If I knew how to do it, I would not be asking. I'm persistent because I really need an answer. Not a coder myself, just learning. Any detailed help would be appreciated. thanks CBroe.

Comment: We are not here to teach people the absolute basics all day long. If you don’t know how a basic loop over an array works - then you should go and find yourself a beginner tutorial that explains this. And if that’s not the part giving you problems - then properly explain, what actually is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress: how to sum meta\_value for a specific meta\_key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68299338/wordpress-how-to-sum-meta-value-for-a-specific-meta-key)

Answer (score 0):

It should be taken in loop. Use below code

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => '_heart_this', 'author' =>  1) );
   //Take all values in array
   $sum = [];
   
   if( $query->have_posts()){ 

    while( $query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();

     {
//Get all posts values one by one
     $value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_heart_this', true );
//Push values in array
     array_push($sum, $value);
     }
    
    endwhile; 
    
   }
    //Sum all values of array to get total amount of meta value
    $sum_final = array_sum ($sum);
    echo $sum_final;
```

Tested & works

Comment: hey, thanks, but for some reason it shows the wrong amount.
My code shows 118, while yours only 3. But the amount should be even higher than 118 when summed of all the meta_value digits. Something is not correct in your code.